# Pass value outside javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, ref

I was just wondering if it was possible to pass a value outside a function so that it will go back to a global variable.

I have an onclick event function that creates a new date when clicked:

```
var beginTimer = new Date ( );    

function count ()
{
    var startTimer = new Date ( );
}
```

I don't want the date to be erased and a new date created everytime I click the button. I need two different variables so that when the user clicks a button once it gets a date and stores as a global variable. When the user clicks the button again it gets a new date and then I want to compare the two.

Comment: You may need to use flags

Comment: Alwasys avoid global variables in Javascript. they are bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is probably a closure. Lets assume you have a button with id as "btn"
With jQuery you could write something as

```
var func = (
       var beginTimer;
       return function(){
            var startTimer = new Date ( );
            //compare beginTimer and startTimer here
            //maybe reaassign beginTimer to new Value
       }
 )();
 $("#btn").click(func);
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Cheers for the help!

Comment: Accepted the answer, but as I'm only new (since yesterday) don't have the rep to up vote. Cheers again.

Answer (score 0):

```
var beginTimer = new Date();
var curTime = null;

function count()
{
   curTime = new Date();
}
```

Yes it's possible

Answer (score 0):

Probably this.

```
var beginTimer = new Date ();    
var startTimer = new Date();
 function count ()
 {
 startTimer=new Date();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
var beginTimer;    

function count ()
{
  if(beginTimer)
  {
    beginTimer = new Date ( );  
  }
  var startTimer = new Date ( );

  //then you can compare the dates 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you create a new variable with out the var keyword it creates it on the global level.
another way of doing that is to use the window obejct:

```
   window["curTime"] = new Date();
```